# one liner shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Can somebody tell me one command which can rename all the files under a directory which are of the form test.c to test.cc without using piping and redirection.

I have written a shell script which contains a loop and does the same work:

`for i in *.c;`
`do`
         `mv $i ${i%c}cc`
`done`

Comment: `for i in *.c; do mv $i ${i%c}cc; done` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find dirname -iname "*.c" -exec mv "{}" "{}"c \;
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to use the above script to convert a *.cc back to *.c file

Comment: Succinctly, you can't.  The `rename .cc .c *.cc` alternative is easy, though (if you have `rename` on the system).

Comment: You could do: `find x -iname "*.cc" -exec mv "{}" \`basename "{}"\`.c \;` but the rename solution is *MUCH* better.

Comment: I think the above script will not work because you are not using basename command properly

Comment: Correct, that script is no good.  Use `rename` as it works in the general case.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with:

```
for i in *.c; do mv $i ${i%c}cc; done
```

It is one line - not even a very long one...

Alternatively, on Linux, there is a `rename` command:

```
rename .c .cc *.c
```

Answer (score 0):

[mmv](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/mmv-copy-append-link-move-multiple-files-under-linux-shell-bash-by-wildcard-patterns-p5/) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `rename` command:

```
rename .c .cc *.c
```

From the man page:

> The rename command is part of the util-linux-ng package and is
>   available from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux-ng/